# Discord.js question regarding roles and message counting

Tags: javascript, discord

How can I get a list of all user IDs from a specific role for example "Twitch Follower", and have the bot count how many messages they sent in a specific channel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MessageManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch):

```js
// <client> is a placeholder for the client object. This could commonly be `message.client`

<client>.channels.cache.get('<channel ID>').messages.fetch(_, true, true).then(messages => {
   console.log(messages.filter(m => m.member.roles.has('<role ID>')).size)
}
```

---

Keep in mind, the limit of messages you can fetch is `100`